# Javascript : For loop inside a For loop. Duplicated items

Tags: javascript, for-loop, search

I made a search bar with three filters: name, a select menu and a checkbox. "Item" comes from a DB and it looks like this

```
{"name":"Daniel","last":"Ambrosino","job":"Col","media":["",""],"avatarUrl":"../../img/87.jpg","timestamp":1593053497294,"_id":"18GQUncoPdVoqOy5"}
```

this for loop goes through that item, "name condition" and "select condition" works fine but then i have to compare the "checkbox" data, **DbMedio** ["",""] with **selectedMedio** [""] and it gives me an "Article" for each item in **DbMedio**

```
for (item of data){        
      
        if (name condition){       //compares what you put in searchbar
      
            if(select condition){        //compares what you selected in the menu

              let dbMedio = Object.values(item.media);
            
              function compare(){
                      for (var i = 0; i < dbMedio.length; i++){            
                          if (selectedMedio.indexOf(dbMedio[i]) >= 0) {
                            document.createElement('article');
                          }
                      }
                  }
              compare(); }}}});}
```

I understand that it has to go through each item inside dbMedio to compare it with selectedMedio. How can i get a single result instead of duplicates?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question entirely, but does this work for the body of `compare`: `if (dbMedio.some(medio => selectedMedio.includes(medio))) {document.createElement('article')}` ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked! Thanks [@ScottSauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet)

```
if (dbMedio.some(medio => selectedMedio.includes(medio))) {document.createElement('article')}
```